# Como simular um cast de uma classe no PHP (que não seja stdClass)?

Tags: php, cast

Parece-me que no java há uma maneira de fazer casts para tornar um determinado objeto instância de outro.

Exemplo:

```
MyClass variable = (MyClass) my_other_class;
```

No php é possível fazer casts de tipos, e até mesmo para objeto, que no caso SEMPRE é o `stdClass`.

Exemplo:

```
$int = 1;
$object = (object) $int;
$array = (array) $int;
$str = (string) $int;
```

Agora se eu tenho, por exemplo, uma classe que defini e quero dar um `cast` de qualquer valor para ela, não é possível.

Exemplo:

```
$arr = array();

$obj = (object) $arr; // Retorna: stdClass

$myObj = (MyObject) $arr; // Retorna: Parse Error
```

Existe alguma maneira de simular isso em PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o Manual do PHP, só existem os tipos de *casts* abaixo, não podendo estes serem personalizados nativamente:

- `(bool)` ou `(boolean)` = Convertendo para booleano
- `(int)` ou `(integer)` = Convertendo para *integer*
- `(float)` = Convertendo para *float*
- `(string)` = Convertendo para *string*
- `(array)` = Convertendo para *array*
- `(object)` = Convertendo para objeto (este sempre será `stdClass`)
- `(resource)` = Convertendo para *resource*
- `(unset)` = Convertendo para *NULL*

Portanto para conseguir converter para um objeto de uma classe específica será necessário criar uma função para fazer isso.